# How to run class A ,Class B and again Class A in testng.xml

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testing, testng, testng.xml

I want to run 'method A' from class A ,then 'method B' from class B, then again 'method A' from class A.
Is it is possible in testng to repeat run, already run classes.
In my case testng not calculating already run classes at the next time in same xml file. Anybody from you can help me?

I create two testng class Class A and Class B. In class A I wrote a method like method A And in class B I wrote another method like method B. And in testng.xml I call Class A method then I call class B method then I again call Class A method. But on first time class A is run after that Class B also run but then execution gets stop and my driver gets closed.and class A which is called at second time doesn't run and testng also not calculating it into the passed, failed or skipped test case.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.